# Securely joining 2 4x4 pieces of wood

Tags: wood, woodworking

I have two 3-ft 4x4 pieces of wood and I would like to join them securely so that I have one 6-ft 4x4 piece of wood.

What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on what you will ultimately be using them for. If you're making a floor lamp, wood glue might be enough. If you need a fence post, you'll need something more.

Comment: I agree with @longneck.  We'd need to know in what direction will force be applied, and how much weight it'll be holding.

Comment: try http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @longneck: wood glue on endgrain is practically useless. I doubt glueing them together end-to-end would even support its own weight.

Comment: I agree with long neck. The only way I know of is splice plates but these have very limited use (similar to how trusses are built as an example).

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. With no indication of hardware restrictions, intended use, or much else, what can be said?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically connect two 4x4s on a deck to build a roof?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14679/how-do-i-vertically-connect-two-4x4s-on-a-deck-to-build-a-roof)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice them up into 1x4s then laminate them with a 1 1/2 foot overlap on alternating pieces.

[image]

That will give you a 6 foot 4x4 from two 3 foot 4x4s.

You'll need lots of wood glue, many clamps and either a good table saw or something equivalent.

The only other ways I can think of doing this involve spending more on hardware than a 6 foot 4x4 probably costs.

Answer (score 0):

Much of it is a matter of what you're trying to do but my first off the cuff suggestion is a "half lap" joint...

Comment: If a half lap joint isn't strong enough, a scarf joint increases the glued area. If the OP is limited to two three foot long pieces, the end result of either joint will not be six feet long, however. Overlap requires additional length.