# How to replace the heavily notched 4x4 support posts on my deck?

Tags: deck, joists

Does anyone have a code compliant idea to replace the support posts I have on my deck? The deck is basically supported by a heavily notched 4x4 that only supports a single 2x6 board that's part of the inner rim band of the deck.

It originally had railing posts on the inside which were the same piece of lumber as the 4x4 support post, but was notched down to only a 2x2" (which of course failed). So I'm replacing the deck railing to be full 4x4s on the outside of the deck band as opposed to the inside.

While I know how to fix the railing, I'd love to have an idea on how to have some decent support for the deck. Most deck bands are 2-ply w/ 2 boards of the same dimension stacked, but mine are different sized.

I drew a picture that hopefully can help visualize this mess of a deck design.

[image]

Comment: is the deck big, how high is it?   does it have something heavy on it, is it sagging?   Some pictures of the deck would help.

Comment: The 2x8 plus 2x6 on the oustide of the deck - where the joist is shown being attached to - does that function as a beam, carrying the load from the joists, or is more of simple rim/band joist?

Comment: Decks I've worked on have the beam (double or triple 2x10s, 2x12's, etc) sitting inboard of the edge of the deck.  They bear on appropriately sized posts, and the joist sit on top of that beam and cantilever out 1 or 2 feet.  Posts for railings are then mounted on the inside of the rim joist with tension ties to prevent movement of the post.

Comment: @DMoore The posts are rotten but not sagging yet. It has nothing on top of it since it's a bit questionable to me in terms of stability. I'm needing to replace those posts but also it'd be preferable to replace it with an installation that's code compliant.

Comment: @SteveSh Yep - the 2x6 is functions as the beam as the joists are attached to it. The 2x8 on the outside edge of the deck is basically a decorative band joist as it handles no load that I can see. There's no cantilever action on this deck like you pointed out in your other comment. A lot of times those decks use Stenson brackets to affix the 2-ply beam onto the top of a 4x4, but my deck can't use a support bracket without the bracket showing on the outside of the 2x8 rim band.

Comment: Code compliance (in Chicago) would require [that they be 6x6's in the first place](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/63826/23295). Check your local codes for whether you *can* put the railing posts on the outside. 'Decent support' for the deck are [these brackets](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75978/what-is-the-right-way-to-mount-a-support-column-to-a-deck-and-to-a-header/76069#76069) mounted to the new 6x6s.... after you dig a hole 3'~5' down and ~4' square for each new post, provisioned to space railing posts less than 5'.

Comment: Meaning, depending on how the posts work out, maybe just do another post instead of a railing post, where otherwise only one of them would be a 4x4 instead of a 6x6 just because you went farther than 5' between them. Then again, digging sucks. - Just to clarify, *'railing posts'* can be 4x4s. *'posts'* must be 6x6s (and the maximum spacing on railing posts is 5').